# Ionic Autocomplete

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am required to have a autocomplete field in my ionic project. I have find the ionic autocomplete plugin & and I have
  tried the following code,

**Plugin:**

```
bower install ionic-autocomplete
```

Html:

`<input type="text" ng-model="search" ionic-autocomplet="{item:countries, onSelect: ToGetData}" /`>

**controller:**

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.countries = [
    {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
    {name: 'Antigua and Barbuda', code: 'AG'},
    {name: 'Bahamas', code: 'BS'},
    {name: 'Cambodia', code: 'KH'},
    {name: 'Cape Verde', code: 'CV'}
  ];
  $scope.ToGetData = function(item) {
    alert('The selected item is: '+item);
  }
});
```

But, It's not working...

I have tried with the following link also, but not working,

> https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete#installation
>
> [How to implement Autocomplete TextBox using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35718996/how-to-implement-autocomplete-textbox-using-angularjs)

Can anyone tell me, how to acheive autocomplete using ionic???

Anyone help will be Appreciated!!!

Comment: any errors ????

Comment: The function "ToGetData" itself not get calling

Answer (score 0):

The corrected code would be as follows :-

In **HTML** :-

```
<input ion-autocomplete type="text" readonly="readonly" class="ion-autocomplete" autocomplete="off" ng-model="model" items-method="ToGetData(query)" item-view-value-key="name" />
```

In **JS** :-

```
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.countries = [
        {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
        {name: 'Antigua and Barbuda', code: 'AG'},
        {name: 'Bahamas', code: 'BS'},
        {name: 'Cambodia', code: 'KH'},
        {name: 'Cape Verde', code: 'CV'}
      ];

// Called everytime the user types something in the search box with the query passed as an argument
      $scope.ToGetData = function(query) {
          if(query) {
            // Filter data based on the query passed
            return item;
          }
          else {
             return $scope.countries; // Display all of the data initially
          }
      }
    });
```

Hope that helps!
Let me know, if it still doesn't work.